# Custom Fonts in Android: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to use a custom font within a TextView of an Android Studio application, but am getting the following error:

[image]

It's a null pointer exception; in the below code, `txt` is `null` for some reason:

**Java**:

```
    TextView txt;

    txt.setText("A");


    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Grundschrift.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

**XML**:

```
android:id="@+id/custom_font"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
```

Thanks!

Comment: For future, please copy the log and paste here, rather than taking a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this part of your,

```
TextView txt;
txt.setText("A");
```

implies that you are calling a method setText() in a null object. To use this method, you have to first initialize the TextView.

so change this

```
TextView txt;
txt.setText("A");

txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Grundschrift.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

to

```
TextView txt; 
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Grundschrift.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
txt.setText("A");
```

Comment: Nolly found the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The line: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke the method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)...` makes me assume that the ploblem is you call `txt.setText("A");` before casting `txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);`.

Instead you should do like this:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
txt.setText("A");
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Grundschrift.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code like the below code:

```
...
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  "fonts/Grundschrift.ttf");
...
```

View's `getContext()` method to get the current context.

Answer (score 1):

You are using txt before initializing, so this one causes a null pointer exception.

Before accessing any variable or object you have to initialize it properly.

like 
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);

txt.setText or something